# How to await when all Disposable elements will be finished?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor, spring-reactive

Lets consider following code:

```
List<Mono<String>> monoList= apiCall();
List<Disposable> disposableList = monoList.stream()
        .map(m-> m.subscribe(str-> {
                           log.info("Mono is finished with "+ str);
                        })
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
// I need to await here
```

I need to await when all mono will be finished.

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Not mixing different streaming APIs you could utilize side effects instead of subscriptions and await completion with [`then()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#then--)

```
Mono<Void> await = Flux
            .fromIterable(apiCall())
            .flatMap(m -> m.doOnSuccess(
                str -> log.info("Mono is finished with "+ str)
            )).then()
```

Comment: An error would result in `await` to complete. If you want to wait for all to terminate, you might want to look into `flatMapDelayError`.

Comment: **An error would result in await to complete** could you please rephrase ?

Comment: An error in a single `Mono` would terminate the final `Mono<Void>` with an error.